# Java draw Strings using data from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, graphics2d

I have a problem with java Graphics, I m writting a program which takes reads a text file and displays some results.

For example:

Text File

```
print("Text",20,100)
print("Hello",135,50)
```

Desired result 2 Strings displayed on the screen.
But I only take the last one.

A sample of my code:

```
ArrayList<String[]> StringsToDraw = new ArrayList<String[]>(); 

//Add some data to the List
StringsToDraw.add(new String[] {"Hello","20","35"}); 
StringsToDraw.add(new String[] {"World","100","100"}); 

@Override 
public void paint(Graphics g){
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
  for(String[] printMe : StringsToDraw){ 
    drawString(g2d, printMe[0], printMe[1], printMe[2]) 
  } 
} 

public void drawString(Graphics g2d, String text, String xString, String yString){ 
    int x = Integer.parseInt(xString); 
    int y = Integer.parseInt(yString); 
    g2d.drawString(text, x, y); 
}
```

How can I change it so it can display both of them?

Comment: Are you sure you are not drawing out of the bounds of the clipping bounds of your Graphics?

Answer (score 0):

You're bounding box might be too small. Try this and see if it works for you:

```
public class Graphics2DTest extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graphics2DTest test = new Graphics2DTest();
        System.out.println(test);
    }

    private List<String[]> StringsToDraw = new ArrayList<String[]>(4);

    public Graphics2DTest() {
        super();

        StringsToDraw.add(new String[] { "Hello", "20", "35" });
        StringsToDraw.add(new String[] { "World", "100", "100" });

        setSize(400, 400);
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (String[] printMe : StringsToDraw) {
            drawString(g2d, printMe[0], printMe[1], printMe[2]);
        }
    }

    public void drawString(Graphics g2d, String text, String xString,
            String yString) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(xString);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(yString);
        g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works. But I forget to mention that I am using a class which extends Canvas and the size is (480,272), and finally a Jpanel in another calss displays the canvas. I tried to change it to JFrame, I made all the required changes but the reuslt was a White colored window. (The Background have been set yellow in the constructor)

Comment: @nask00s - alright, have you confirmed the positioning and size of your canvas? You can do this by setting the background to something not used in your other UI components (e.g lime green) and then running your program. If the position and size look off after that then you know its a layout manager problem.